# Box API 2.0 doesn't accept auth_token, whereas v1.0 does

Tags: box-api

I'm trying to use the Box v2 API by following the [Getting Started](http://developers.box.com/get-started). All is fine until I receive the auth_token from Box, and when I use it to do anything, for example the sample call:

```
curl https://www.box.com/api/2.0/folders/0 \
-H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN"
```

I get a `401 Unauthorized` reply.

I'm sure I'm sending the auth_token correctly, because the same auth_token works when I use it for the Box v1 API.

Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Can you try https://api.box.com instead of https://www.box.com/api

Answer (score 1):

Your curl request looks right, so the 401 probably means that your auth_token has expired or is somehow invalid.  There is the chance that your auth token contains a double quote, which could confuse curl.

My recommendation is to go through the process and get a new auth token.   If that doesn't solve the problem, then send Box an email to api[at]boxDOTcom with details.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm sending it without quotes, since I use the same variable to make a call to Box API v 1.0 and it works.